# angular 7 import html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

importing html file

```
import html  from "./views/htmlpage.html";
```

> but when assigning html to local declared variable it is giving
>   undefined, see screenshots

[image]

[image: html showing on hover]

any suggestions whats wrong
Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the above code.

Comment: Your breakpoint is before assignment

Comment: import html from "./views/htmlpage.html";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public htmls: string = "";
  constructor(private readonly router: Router, private cookieService: CookieService, private readonly productService: ProductService, private readonly sharedService: SharedService, private toastr: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef) {

    this.htmls = html;
  }
}

Comment: @ritaj screen shots are taken after line execution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try assigning html to your variable in ngOnInit